# feh on startup.... sort of

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I am having some problems with getting feh to load at startup.  I'm new to Linux but have been in IT for years.. any help is much appreciated. I am running Raspbian Stretch. It's a Pi 3.

I have a NAS and I have created the mounts in FStab so I mount a folder called pictures to /media.  This works. 
I then created a shell script and modified its permissions so it runs `chmod 775 /startup.sh`. The location of the startup.sh file is: `/home/pi` 
My startup.sh script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
bash feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B black -F -Z -z -r /media/
```

I then added an entry to the autostart file located at
`/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi`.

The autostart now looks like:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@point-rpi
@epiphany /home/pi/startup.sh
```

I then rebooted the Pi... here's the weird thing! 
When I reboot my Pi, it opens a web browser and downloads the startup.sh file but it doesn't seem to execute it.
I tried changing (within the autostartfile) `@epiphany /home/pi/startup.sh` to
`@terminal /home/pi/startup.sh`.

Nothing happens.  Does that mean @epiphany is the program (webbrowser) it uses to open the script with?  What else could I:
1.  Install to use to execute the script or 
2.  Is there something like terminal I could use (I tried @bash) but it didn't work either.

Here is the output of `ls -al /home/pi/startup.sh`:

```
$ ls -al /home/pi/startup.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 78 Feb 28 19:27 /home/pi/startup.sh
```

Comment: you say a "web browser" downloads the startup.sh file? ... web browsers don't automatically execute .sh files, so that's something to consider

Comment: Sorry I missed these alerts i assumed it would email me to say people had commented.
Ok so output of ls -al /home/pi/startup.sh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -al /home/pi/startup.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 78 Feb 28 19:27 /home/pi/startup.sh

Answer (score 1):

Replace the call to **@epiphany** to a call to **@lxterminal**. Epiphany is a browser and obviously the wrong program to execute bash scripts.

LXTerminal is the Terminal program of LXDE, the Lightweight X Desktop Environment. LXDE has been heavily customised but is still the foundation of the "Raspberry Pi Desktop".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `@/bin/bash /home/pi/startup.sh`? This should do the trick.

Another option would be to use `/etc/rc.local`. Just add `/home/pi/startup.sh` to the end of the file.

Comment: shouldn't this be `/bin/bash`  ...as `which bash` points to `/bin/bash` in raspberian

Answer (score 0):

Try a different startup location. try enabling autologin then adding

```
sleep 10 &
sudo feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B black -F -Z -z -r /media/ &
```

to the end of `/etc/profile` .
(*make sure you keep the & symbols*)

Comment: probably won't work because it might execute before x starts. it might work with the `sleep 10 &`, though

Comment: I've also heard `/etc/profile` isn't the correct place to put startup scripts... but it's worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

This is the most elegant solution to auto-launch FEH in Rasbian. I have performed this on both a Raspberry Pi3B and a Zero. While both where the latest updated version (Dec 2019) they did have a difference! In Rasbian it does boot to the full GUI for myself, nothing custom.

This is a two step process. You can launch FEH automatically when you open the Command Window:
In /home/pi using sudo nano .bash_aliases   add in the FEH command. CTL O then CTL X (save and exit). To show it works, simply launch the command window, IF FEH does not launch there is a problem. 
You can read more on this here:  https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/bashrc.md

To then auto-launch the command window on a reboot, this is where there were some differences. In both cases you are adding in the autostart file the line:
@lxterminal

In the Pi Zero add the entry to the autostart file located at /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi.
For the Pi3B I had to go /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi
Permissions were an issue so don't forget to use:
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
You can read about that:  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=227191

As an FYI, here is my FEH command that I put in the .bash_aliases file
feh -Y -x -q -D 12 -B black --auto-rotate -F -Z -r /home/pi/Pictures/